# Did Vin MoCap the Dance?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

We all know Vin Diesel is famous for his [silky moves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JD2Mb8pM6E8)...

[image]

Is there anything to substantiate the claim that Vin Diesel was himself the model for the Motion Capture of Groot's already infamous pre-credit jive in [*Guardians of the Galaxy*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/)?

Comment: What is the purpose of the picture?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander, that's Vin Diesel. I included a link to the video, but some people are unable to watch Videos (at work!).

Comment: I know that it is Vin Diesel. Did you post the video/picture to prove that Diesel can dance?

Comment: Yes. It was either this or 'Drunk in Love' ;)

Comment: I know the guy who animated that bit - I'll find out for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I messaged Jesse Hildreth, the ILM animator who was responsible for that sublime little dancing Groot at the end and he told me that Vin Diesel definitely did not perform mo-cap for that shot, and in fact it was James Gunn who performed it for the reference footage!

Jesse was also responsible for most of Star-Lord's helmet shots, some close-ups on Rocket's hands and a couple of Milano shots - all cool stuff!

UPDATE: Jesse just sent me a link with the following quote:

> "I'm not motion-captured, but I'm motion-referenced and that is 100%
>   me dancing..."
>   James Gunn

Read more at http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/MarvelFreshman/news/?a=105173#1ZQTzc6HS9QULsvb.99

Comment: Whoa, it finally pays to have actual industry insiders among the users.

Comment: And now I'm thirsty for a couple of Milano shots...